# p-selectButton single value with uncheck

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to have a p-selectButton single-choice with the possibility to uncheck an option.

With multiple set true it is possible to uncheck an option, but it is possible to choose multiple options. With multiple set to false it is not possible to choose multiple options but i can not uncheck an option.

This works:

```
<p-selectButton [multiple]="true" (onChange)="onChange()" [options]="options"></p-selectButton>
```

```
onChange() {
// choose the last option 
// (as the newly selected one is always added at the end of the array)
}
```

Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: In the onChange() Event remove everything, except the last one. (multiple=true)

Option 2: Consider using `<p-toggleButton></p-toggleButton>`